# Can't find SSH keys settings under travis project settings

Tags: travis-ci, ssh-keys

My CI project is dependent on another private repo. So I refer to the [document](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies/#using-an-existing-key) to upload the private key using

```
➜ travis sshkey --upload ~/.ssh/id_travis_rsa --pro
Updating ssh key for Jeff-Tian/uni-sso with key from /Users/tianjef/.ssh/id_travis_rsa

Current SSH key: key for clone k8s-config
Finger print:    65:25:66:26:4d:5d:9f:ac:25:ba:ea:be:c4:d5:e3:5f
```

From the above I double checked the finger print, and compares to the github ssh keys:

[image]

They are matched.

However, the travis build still fails by:

(https://travis-ci.com/github/Jeff-Tian/uni-sso/builds/161350192)

```
$ git clone git@github.com:Jeff-Tian/k8s-config.git ${HOME}/k8s-config
Cloning into '/home/travis/k8s-config'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.114.4' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
The command "git clone git@github.com:Jeff-Tian/k8s-config.git ${HOME}/k8s-config" failed and exited with 128 during .
```

And then I check the settings on travis settings, can't find the ssh keys settings pane:

[image]

### Help:

Where goes wrong? Is it a Travis CI bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the ssh keys config is only available for **private** repos.

The issue here is the main repo is **public**, but when deploy it, a **private** repo need to be downloaded. This scenario is not covered by the [official document](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies/#using-an-existing-key).

The workaround is to switch copying the **private** repo via `https` instead of `ssh`, so no need to upload the `ssh` keys.

By setting up the `GH_TOKEN` in the setting, and then write that token to `.netrc` file. Then copy the **private** repo using https is working:

.travis.yml:

```
  - echo -e "machine github.com\n  login $GH_TOKEN" > ~/.netrc
  - git clone https://github.com/Jeff-Tian/k8s-config.git ${HOME}/k8s-config
```

Comment: This is very helpful. But your ~/.netrc file has some error. Should have a line login with username, and a password line with the token:

`- echo -e "machine github.com\n  login ci_user \n  password $GH_TOKEN" > ~/.netrc`